# Combine two resource key for single label .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

For making an existing site to multilingual, I follow globalization technique, I have created 3 resource files for different content like label & header text file, grid header text file etc...
Now I have two keys in different resource files i.e Email and Message, at a third place I want to show both these keyword together i.e Email message. Do I need to create third key or I can concatenate already existing keys. Currently I am using below two codes

```
For showing directly on page:
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceLabelButton", "Email")

For showing as text of any control like Textbox, label:
Text ="<%$ Resources:ResourceContent, Email %>"
```

I can concatenate two resource string on .cs page but it will increase timeline, so please suggest so I can only change on .aspx pages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET tag attribute values that use <%$ Something: Something Else %> are of a special syntax called [ASP.NET Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx). Using them as attribute values are pretty much all-or-nothing; there's no way to add any code into the ASPX file to manipulate what those expressions evaluate to. You'll have to do this in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a separate resource entry for "Email Message" instead of concatenating "Email" and "Message". To understand why, look at Spanish:

- Email = *Correo electrónico*
- Message = *Mensaje*

Simple concatenation gives you *Correo electrónico Mensaje*. **This is wrong.** The correct translation is:

- Email Message = *Mensaje de correo electrónico*

Notice that in the translation, the order of "Email" and "Message" has been reversed, and a new word (*de*, which means "of") has been inserted between them.

On the other hand, look at the translations for "New Message" and "Last Message":

- New Message = *Mensaje nuevo*
- Last Message = *Último mensaje*

As you can see, there are complex rules that govern when to reverse the order of words and when to insert *de*. These rules, of course, are different in other languages.

So in general, you should never concatenate localized words or phrases to form a longer phrase.
**Always provide a separate resource entry for every phrase.**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and I solved it by using this option instead:

```
<asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Email: <%= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceContent", "Email") %>">
```

For local Resources, use the `GetLocalResourceObject` method instead of `GetGlobalResourceObject`

Answer (score 0):

If this value is being used very often make a third key for the same, else concatenate at runtime

Comment: How to concatenate at runtime?

Comment: you can do it in .cs as you know, but I dont know  how it is to be done in aspx page for global resource, not sure where but I read somewhere sometime back it is a known globalization issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNameAndNos" runat="server">
<%= ""+ Resources.Resources.Name + "/" + Resources.Resources.Nos %>  
</asp:Label>
```

Instead of using inside Text property use the above way